# Triggering a button click with the enter key in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Please forgive me in advance, as I am very new to Python. I'm putting together this code for a very simple rate calculator and want to make it where when the Enter key is pressed the program calculates the total (executes the calculate command). Python returns an error saying that Calculate is not defined, however I've defined it several lines above. Any ideas?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()

class Adder(ttk.Frame):

"""The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()


    def on_quit(self):
        """Exits program."""
        quit()

    def calculate(self, *args):
        """Calculates the sum of the two inputted numbers."""
        num1 = int(self.num1_entry.get())
        num2 = float(self.num2_entry.get())
        num3 = ((num1/2000) * num2)
        self.answer_label['text'] = num3





    def init_gui(self):
        self.root.title('Rate Calculator')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self.root)

        self.menu_file = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.on_quit)

        self.menu_edit = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)

        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_file, label='File')
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_edit, label='Edit')

        self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.num1_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=5)
        self.num1_entry.grid(column=1, row = 2)

        self.num2_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=5)
        self.num2_entry.grid(column=3, row=2)

        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Calculate',
                command=self.calculate)
        self.calc_button.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=4)

        self.answer_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Answer',
                height=100)
        self.answer_frame.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.answer_label = ttk.Label(self.answer_frame, text='')
        self.answer_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Labels that remain constant throughout execution.
    ttk.Label(self, text='Rate Calculator').grid(column=0, row=0,
            columnspan=4)
    ttk.Label(self, text='Weight').grid(column=0, row=2,
            sticky='w')
    ttk.Label(self, text='Rate').grid(column=2, row=2,
            sticky='w')

    ttk.Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(column=0,
            row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='ew')

    for child in self.winfo_children():
        child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


root.bind('<Return>', calculate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your program, but you want `self.calculate`, just like you have in the `self.calc_button`.

Comment: please check intendation

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you. It appears to work fine for me on Python 3.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reorganised your code slightly so it now calls the `calculate` method either when you press the button or when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def on_quit(self):
        """Exits program."""
        tk.quit()

    def calculate(self, *args):
        """Calculates the sum of the two inputted numbers."""
        num1 = int(self.num1_entry.get())
        num2 = float(self.num2_entry.get())
        num3 = ((num1/2000) * num2)
        self.answer_label['text'] = num3

    def init_gui(self):
        self.root.title('Breakbulk Rate Calculator')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.root)

        self.menu_file = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.on_quit)

        self.menu_edit = tk.Menu(self.menubar)

        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_file, label='File')
        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_edit, label='Edit')

        self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.num1_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=5)
        self.num1_entry.grid(column=1, row = 2)

        self.num2_entry = ttk.Entry(self, width=5)
        self.num2_entry.grid(column=3, row=2)

        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Calculate',
                command=self.calculate)
        self.calc_button.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=4)

        self.answer_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Answer',
                height=100)
        self.answer_frame.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nesw')

        self.answer_label = ttk.Label(self.answer_frame, text='')
        self.answer_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        # Labels that remain constant throughout execution.
        ttk.Label(self, text='Breakbulk Rate Calculator').grid(column=0, row=0,
                columnspan=4)
        ttk.Label(self, text='Weight').grid(column=0, row=2,
                sticky='w')
        ttk.Label(self, text='Rate').grid(column=2, row=2,
                sticky='w')

        ttk.Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(column=0,
                row=1, columnspan=4, sticky='ew')

        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

        self.root.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.calculate())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

To create a callback with the proper signature for `.bind` I've used a lambda function that simply discards the Event object that gets passed to it.

I also got rid of the evil `from tkinter import *` wildcard import.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from this part of your code

```
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)
```

change it to

```
root.bind('<Return>', self.calculate)
```

it will work.

Comment: @D.Redmond Ah. That's because you have the `root.bind` call outside the class definition. So you need to reorganize your code a little. Either put that call inside your class, and change it to `self.root.bind`, or save a reference to the `Adder` instance eg, `adder = Adder(root); root.bind('<Return>', adder.calculate)`

Comment: I'm getting a new error now.It says TypeError: calculate() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Comment: @D.Redmond Sorry about that. I forgot that `.bind` behaves a little differently to the Widget `command` arg. A `bind` callback gets passed the Event which triggers it. It's probably simplest to just write a new callback for the `bind` and have that callback call the original `calculate`.